# Swift 3: How can I add a local database storage on my app?

Tags: swift, sqlite, local-database

I am developing an app and the info i get on the app is linked to the external database. Now if the user wants to save the details they press the button and it saves on their local storage. What are the possibilities and how can I integrate local storage with the app?

Comment: What have you looked into so far?

Comment: hi, i tried to looked into @ Realm and firebase and Sqllite

Comment: What kind of data are you looking store e.g. size?

Comment: @CoolPenguin i m looking where the user can create a note and/or they can mark as fav and save the contact details

Answer (score 0):

Try using **UserDefaults** for *persistent data*:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(myData, forKey: "myKey")
```

Then to retrieve:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let myString = defaults.string(forKey: "myKey")
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: I tried doing it but its not working for me.. not too sure where do i add this block of code. My knowledge and experience with swift is limited

Comment: Sorry about that. What do you mean by its not working for you? You can add this in pretty much any function.

Comment: Yes sure. You can email it to tibor@phonefiveme.com

Comment: Hi @CoolPenguin  hope you keeping well. I have emailed you my project. Did you received it?

Comment: @SarahMalik sorry I don't have the time to commit to helping you out with an entire project